# Missing Outputs with ArcPy RasterToASCII and ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, optimization, parallel-processing, multithreading

When I use ThreadPoolExecutor, I am missing a random number of expected outputs. I tried making an MRE to show what I am trying to do. The first MRE works but when I run a second MRE (which is closer to what I'm trying to do but requires an ArcGIS Pro license/arcpy package), it runs without error but is missing a random number of outputs. I'm wondering if this is a race conditions issue and if there is a work around? I tried using a context manager as well and it did not help.

MRE that runs and generates all expected outputs, 100 .csv files and 100 .xlxs files:

```
import numpy
import glob
import pandas
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Create dummy .csv files with map()
myNumberList = range(100)

def make_csv(number):
    a = numpy.asarray([number])
    numpy.savetxt("foo_"+str(number)+".csv", a, delimiter=",")

result_list = list(map(make_csv, myNumberList))

# Test ThreadPoolExecutor to generate .xlsx for each .csv
myCsvList = glob.glob('*.csv')
def make_xlsx(csv):
      df_new = pandas.read_csv(csv)
      xlsx = pandas.ExcelWriter(csv.strip('.csv') + '.xlsx')
      df_new.to_excel(xlsx, index = False)
      xlsx.save()
    
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10)
results = pool.map(make_xlsx, myCsvList)

for res in results:
       print(res)

pool.shutdown()
```

An MRE that requires an ArcGISPro license (this never produces all of the expected outputs when range is set to a large number (say >100) in `myNumberList = range()`:

```
import time
import glob
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import arcpy
import os

# Create dummy TIF rasters with map()

myNumberList = range(100)

def create_ascii(number):
    string_out_name = 'emptytiff_' + str(number) + '.tif'
    tif = arcpy.CreateRasterDataset_management(out_path = wd, out_name = string_out_name, pixel_type = '8_BIT_UNSIGNED', number_of_bands = "1")

result_list = list(map(create_ascii, myNumberList))

# Test ThreadPoolExecutor to generate a .asc for each tif

tif_list = glob.glob('*.tif')

def create_tif(raster):
    path_ascii_out = os.path.join(wd, (raster.strip('.tif') + '.asc'))
    arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(raster, path_ascii_out)
    
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10)
results = pool.map(create_tif, tif_list)

for res in results:
       print(res)

pool.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading and ArcPy is a topic that comes up from time to time, usually on [Esri Community](https://community.esri.com).  I believe part of my answer from [Does arcpy support multithreading? - Esri Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/does-arcpy-support-multithreading/td-p/819315) a few years ago is still applicable today:

> The short answer is that Esri doesn't officially state whether ArcPy supports
> multi-threading or multi-processing.  Over the years Esri staff occasionally
> comment in forums and at conferences that ArcPy does not support multi-threading
> and you should use multi-processing instead, but I would not go as far as saying
> those comments by Esri staff make for an official statement on the topic.
>
> ...
>
> The ArcGIS Pro framework, or parts of it, is definitely multi-threaded, and
> ArcGIS Pro has more geoprocessing tools that support parallel processing, but
> I don't think any of that implies ArcPy supports multi-threading in ArcGIS Pro.

When it comes to multithreading and ArcPy, the take away messages for me has been "use at your own risk" and "results will vary."

In this specific case, it appears that one tool, [Create Raster Dataset (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-raster-dataset.htm), works with multithreading and a different one doesn't, [Raster to ASCII (Conversion) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-ascii.htm).  Since the code is proprietary and we can't consult the source, we are left to speculate as to why, and more importantly find a workaround if possible.  In terms of speculating, I would guess that RasterToASCII is older code that simply isn't thread-safe, so it is more prone to issues when running it in multiple threads at the same time.

When multiprocessing and multithreading, error handling ([8. Errors and Exceptions - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)) is especially important since errors are just crashing/stopping processes and threads, and any errors and tracebacks aren't going to show up in a console unless code is specifically written to trap and share the information back to the main body of code.  When calling ArcGIS geoprocessing tools via ArcPy, a [Result - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/result.htm) is returned. I strongly encourage using those objects along with error trapping to figure out whether another process or thread is executing as expected.

Using Result objects and error handling, you can see that RasterToASCII isn't generating any errors, which is good on one level.  However, the tool is occassionally (and seemingly randomly) returning Result objects with a status of 5, which is 'Failed.'  Since errors aren't being generated, and failed results are getting returned, the issue can be worked around by re-running the tool if it first comes back with a failure.

```py
import time
import glob
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import arcpy
import os


# Test ThreadPoolExecutor to generate empty tif
myNumberList = range(100)
wd = # path to working directory

def create_tif(number):
    kwargs = {
        'out_path': wd,
        'out_name': f'emptytiff_{number:03}.tif',
        'pixel_type': '8_BIT_UNSIGNED',
        'number_of_bands': 1
    }
    attempts = 1
    try:
        res = arcpy.management.CreateRasterDataset(**kwargs)
        while (res.status in (5,6) and attempts <= 3):
            res = arcpy.management.CreateRasterDataset(**kwargs)
            attempts += 1
        return (res, attempts)
    except Exception as err:
        return err

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as pool:
    result = list(pool.map(create_tif, myNumberList))

del result, pool
print(len(glob.glob(os.path.join(wd,'*.tif'))))

# Test ThreadPoolExecutor to generate a .asc for each tif
tif_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(wd,'*.tif'))

def create_ascii(raster):
    kwargs = {
        'in_raster': raster,
        'out_ascii_file': raster.strip('.tif') + '.asc'
    }
    attempts = 1
    try:
        res = arcpy.conversion.RasterToASCII(**kwargs)
        while (res.status in (5,6) and attempts <= 3):
            res = arcpy.conversion.RasterToASCII(**kwargs)
            attempts += 1
        return (res, attempts)
    except Exception as err:
        return err

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as pool:
    result = list(pool.map(create_ascii, tif_list))

del result, pool
print(len(glob.glob(os.path.join(wd,'*.asc'))))
```